# flutter run vs install command

Tags: flutter, command-line, terminal

I am a beginner in flutter programming. When I learned a few commands, I got a doubt that is

difference between **flutter run** and **flutter install** command?

Using flutter help commands, I got this

**install**: Install a flutter app on an attached device.

**run**: Run your Flutter app on an attached device.

But what is the difference and what actually happening in device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obvious actually, `flutter run` lets you debug and test your app in emulator or device before build it, you can use restart, hotstart etc and continue develop your app. `flutter install` will install the app to device after build it as apk.